# Appium desktop not launching Appium Inspector UI in MAC

Tags: appium, appium-desktop

I have installed Appium desktop and Appium Inspector on my mac machine. However, when I start the Appium server and click the search icon (it is supposed to open the inspector tool) it's navigating to the Github page.

I have separately installed appium-inspector via dmg file, Still, I am not able to open from the server. is there any plugin or installation step I am missing?

Comment: What is the Appium version you have installed?

Answer (score 0):

Appium desktop and appium server are now separate. Download the appium inspector from this [page](https://github.com/appium/appium-inspector/releases)

Comment: yes I downloaded and Installed , However appium server is not launching it.. is there anyway to  can configure inspector path in Appium server?

Comment: None that I know of. You need to start it as a separate application. Just search it from the mac spotlight search (appium desktop) then launch it